# multiprocessing / multithreading in python to download files

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a csv file which contains the list of symbols I wish to pull from yahoo finance. (about 3000 of them)

```
df = pandas.read_csv('ticker_file.csv')
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()

for each_code in df['Symbol']:  # got it from pandas website "Remote Data Access"
    get_prices = web.DataReader(each_code, 'yahoo', start, end)
    get_prices.to_csv(each_code + '.csv')
```

It takes about 2.5 - 3 seconds to pull one `symbol` and save it to `csv`.

I'm wondering, would it be possible / quicker to use multiprocessing / hyper threading to quicken this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily use a multiprocessing pool of workers. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html and the first example given (using a pool of 5 workers).  It would look something like this:

```
def f(each_code):
    start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime.today()
    get_prices = web.DataReader(each_code, 'yahoo', start, end)
    get_prices.to_csv(each_code + '.csv')

p = Pool(20)
p.map(f, df['Symbol'])
```

Can't say whether or not it will speed things up. It likely will, as long as the website doesn't complain.

Comment: Note: I assumed you had a typo between `each_code` and `each_ticker`, and so, made everything just use `each_code`

Comment: `get_prices.to_csv` runs the risk of corrupting or overwriting data. It would be safer to return the row to the parent to write to the csv. In that case, `imap_unordered` would be a good choice.

Comment: indeed, i thought that as well at first glance, until i realized that a unique file was being written for each ticker --- so there will be no collisions trying to write to the file --- and I didn't want to make the solution overly complicated

Comment: Hmm, Thanks for the input! I'll check it out. :)

Comment: I tried the code for a list of symbols, however when I run p.map it returns with a set of None. How to get the results in a data frame like we can do in a  for loop by appending

Comment: Does anyone know if this speeds things up?